# What does `1..something` mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
1..z
</script>
```

This gives no syntax or runtime error. Looks like number and variable name can be any other (`123..qwerty`).  I'm wondering what does this statement mean?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Is **not** a range, the `1..z` expression will simply return `undefined`.

Why?

The first dot ends a representation of a [Numeric Literal](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.8.3), giving you a `Number` primitive:

```
var n = 1.;
```

The grammar of a Numeric Literal is expressed like this:

```
DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigitsopt ExponentPartopt
```

As you can see the DecimalDigits part after the dot is *optional* (opt suffix).

The second dot is the property accessor, it will try only to get the `z` property, which is `undefined` because it doesn't exist on the `Number.prototype` object:

```
1..z; // undefined
1..toString(); // "1"
```

Is equivalent to access a property with the bracket notation property accessor:

```
1['z']; // or
1['toString']();
```

Comment: I started flipping through "JavaScript: The good parts" going "I don't remember ranges in javascript." Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 5):

Combine these:

```
alert(1.foo); // --> parse error
alert(1.4.foo); // --> undefined - number 1.4 doesn't have the property foo
alert(1.); // --> 1 (?)
```

To the conclusion:

```
alert(1..foo); // --> undefined
```