# Usage of toString in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm reading through Douglas Crockford's *[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)*, and I'm at the point where he defines a *fade* function. Part of this code boils down to this:

```
var level = 1;
var hex = level.toString(16);
```

So I run this in my browser's console to see what I get....

```
var level = 1;
level.toString(16);
```

Hey, it returns "`1`"... Fabuloso! Wunderbar!

Then to be cheeky, I try this to see what I get...

```
1.toString(16);
```

And I get

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

What the what? If `level` is a variable equal to 1, and running this method on level works fine, then why doesn't running this method on the actual number 1 work? I tried a similar experiment with the `toPrecision()` method and that worked fine in both cases. What's the issue here? Is this another one of those inherent flaws in the JavaScript implementation, or am I missing something? I am testing in Google Chrome.

Related: Stack Overflow question *[Why don't number literals have access to Number methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046342)*.

Comment: Related: [What's wrong with this code? I am not able to extend the Number object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6833521/), [What does `1..something` mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2300197/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's just a language grammar limitation.

Since `1.` is a legal literal number (and `1.t` is not) the tokeniser will split this into the following tokens:

```
1.
toString
(
)
```

And that's an illegal sequence of tokens.  It's `object method`, instead of `object . method`.

In the working versions in @Joey's answer, the braces prevent the tokenizer from treating the dot as part of the number literal instead of as a separate token, as does writing:

```
1.0.toString()
```

or

```
1..toString()
```

since the tokenizer knows that the second dot *must* be a token on its own, and not part of the number literal.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. Winner, winner, chicken dinner.

Comment: However, the parser *should* know that identifiers that begin with a number are illegal, and therefore it should be evaluated as a number. Perhaps a limitation?

Comment: @peter it's nothing to do with identifiers.  The tokenizer will grab the first dot as part of a "number token", which means it's no longer available to be a token in its own right.

Comment: I think the parser knows it's a number... it just doesn't know where the number ends, as Alnitak explains. Both 1 and 1. are valid, equivalent numbers in javascript. So the parser is not recognizing the dot as indicating a method, but rather as a decimal with invalid characters after it. I get the same error if I just put 1.bork into the console. But by having two decimal points, js knows the second dot means a method is coming next. So using my own example I get a valid response when I try 3.14159.toString(16) because there are two dots.

Comment: Good grief!! An intelligent conversation about parsers and tokenisers on SO! What will they think of next - quoting the spec?? :-o

Comment: Thanks @Bob, that's a good explanation. Alnitak, I was mostly alluding to the fact that the parser was not able to properly decompose the expression. I would have thought that the lexer would force the only possible match?

Comment: @Peter it's too late for the parser by then - the lexer already made the decision to consume the dot as part of the number literal.

Answer (score 4):

You need 1..toString or (1).toString to get the number literal

Comment: Ok, that gives me the how, but not the why. Why does 3.14159.toPrecision(3) work fine, but 1.toString(16) give me an error? They're both methods on the number object.

Answer (score -2):

level is a variable (and thus an object).

1 is a literal. They are not objects and the interpreter thinks about them completely differently.

http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/bridge/1998/res/javascript/javascript-tutorial.html#4

Comment: numbers are objects, and number methods can act upon them. Alnitak hit on the right answer by explaining that the dot is ambiguous to the javascript parser as either a decimal point or as indicating a property of that object. Or maybe not ambiguous, as javascript unambiguously sees the first dot as a decimal point and not an indicator of an object property. But if you try 1..toString(16), we're all in coolsville. :-)

Comment: @BobRalian Actually numbers are not objects - they're primitive value types - they're just readily boxed to `Number` objects

Comment: Or in JavaScript: _coerced_ into `Number` objects.