# javascript number property syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I access a property of an integer with a single dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380077/why-cant-i-access-a-property-of-an-integer-with-a-single-dot)

I was reading an article, and came across the strange behaviour of javascript toFixed method. I don't understand the reason for the last statement. Can anyone explain please?

`(42).toFixed(2);` // "42.00"  **Okay**

`42.toFixed(2);` // SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

`42..toFixed(2);` // "42.00" **This really seems strange**

Comment: It might make more sense to you if you used `42.0.toFixed(2)`

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3297392/1048572

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number in JavaScript is basically this in regex:

```
[+-]?[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?
```

Note that the quantifiers are greedy. This means when it sees:

```
42.toFixed(2);
```

It reads the `42.` as the number and then is immediately confronted with `toFixed` and doesn't know what to do with it.

In the case of `42..toFixed(2)`, the number is `42.` but not `42..` because the regex only allows one dot. Then it sees the `.` which can only be a call to a member, which is `toFixed`. Everything works fine.

As far as readability goes, `(42).toFixed(2)` is far clearer as to its intention.

Answer (score 3):

The dot is ambiguous: decimal point or call member operator. Therefore the error.

`42..toFixed(2);` is equivalent to `(42.).toFixed(2)`