# Calling member function of number literal

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call literal functions, but I get weird behavior.

Consider this code which returns `true`:

```
23 === (23)
```

When I write try the following:

```
(23).toFixed(2)
```

I get the expected result `"23.00"` but when I try `23.toFixed(2)` I get this error.

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The answers by [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555864) and [icktoofay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555871) are correct in all ways, however, I'd like to get down a bit, abstraction-wise: Let's see what's really happening according to the javascript specification.

[Section 7.8.3](http://es5.github.io/#x7.8.3) of the spec defines numeric literals. We can see the following:

```
DecimalLiteral ::
    DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigits(opt) ExponentPart(opt)
    . DecimalDigits ExponentPart(opt)
    DecimalIntegerLiteral ExponentPart(opt)

DecimalIntegerLiteral ::
    0 
    NonZeroDigit DecimalDigits(opt)
```

A `DecimalLiteral`, a number, is a bunch of decimal digits, possibly followed by a dot, which is possibly followed by other digits (all of which can be followed by an exponent, `e12` for instance). In other words, `42.` is legal and equal to `42` and `3e2` is equal to `300`.

Note how if we have a dot, we either expect it to be followed by more digits/exponent, or be followed by nothing. However, and this is the important part, *the dot is part of the number*. Remember this as we move to look how the dot operator, `obj.prop`, is dealt with.

[Section 11.2.1, Property Accessors](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1) describes the dot and bracket notation for member access:

```
MemberExpression . IdentifierName
```

`CallExpression` is for function calls, which we don't care about. Notice how we're expecting a `MemberExpression` (which can be a `DecimalLiteral` - but don't take my word for it, look and see whether I'm right).

See that little dot? It's logical to jump forward and say "well, there's a dot in the scheme here...and there's a dot in `4.foo`...so why is there an error?" Alas my hypothetical friend whom I use for these sentences, you forgot how the `DecimalLiteral` looks like! Let's go over two examples and see what happens.

```
42.foo
^
```

The caret represents the character we're on. So far, we're inside `DecimalLiteral / DecimalIntegerLiteral / NonZeroDigit` (that's quite a mouthful). Let's move to the next character:

```
42.foo
 ^
```

Still part of the number, a perfectly valid `DecimalDigit`.

```
42.foo
  ^
```

ok, so we're out of the `DecimalIntegerLiteral` part. Here's the same diagram on the scheme:

```
DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigits(opt) ExponentPart(opt)
                      ^
```

So we're on a dot, which is a perfectly valid part of a number. Now we consume it, *as part of the number*, and move on:

```
42.foo
   ^
```

`f` is neither part of `DecimalDigits` nor of `ExponentPart`, we're out of the number now. So...what now? What's that `f`? It's not part of anything. Maybe it's a property accessor? Let's take a look at the scheme:

```
MemberExpression . IdentifierName
      ^
```

We're definitely on `MemberExpression`, but we don't have a dot which follows it - that dot is already part of the number. We've reached a syntactical error: we stop execution and throw it. Hopefully you don't live in a glass house.

Hopefully now you understand why `42..foo` works. Once we're out of the `MemberExpression`, we face another dot:

```
              42..foo
                 ^
MemberExpression . IdentifierName
                 ^
```

Followed by a perfectly legal `IdentifierName`.

Of course, there're several other ways to separate the dot from the number. One way, as you showed, is to surround the literal in parentheses: `(42).foo`. When we've reached the parentheses end, we're out of the `MemberExpression`, and on the dot. Another way is to insert a space: `42 .foo`, since a space can't be part of the number, and it's neutral for the parser, so it won't raise an error.

Answer (score 36):

Unlike Ruby (for example), The Javascript parser considers a `.` following digits to be part of the number. So the parser sees the tokens:

`23.` `toFixed` `(` `2` `)`

which is a syntax error, because the word `toFixed` immediately following a floating point number doesn't make sense. A language such as Ruby that accepts this syntax would see the following tokens:

`23` `.` `toFixed` `(` `2` `)`

Answer (score 23):

Consider:

```
5.
```

Is that the floating-point literal `5.` or an integer `5` followed by a dot? You don't know; it's ambiguous. JavaScript takes the former view. In JavaScript's view, you've got a floating-point literal followed by an identifier (then followed by a left parenthesis, number, and a right parenthesis).

Some people work around this by using two dots:

```
23..toFixed(2)
```

Since a floating-point literal can only possibly have one decimal point, the other dot is a literal dot token.