# Javascript Function toString

Tags: javascript, numbers

See the code below:

```
2.toString();   // error
2..toString();  // "2"
2...toString(); // error
```

I want to know why `2..toString()` can run without errors and what happens when it runs?

Can somebody explain it?

Comment: Curious where you came accross this example code. It's somewhat suprising that it is essentially the same as from the example link provided in @Nikolay's answer...

Comment: @Zach L I have seen it before some other place and I cannot understand it all the time.Today,I saw it again.So,I came here for the answer.It did surprise me when I opened the link provided by Nikolay,becasue I just saw another web site very similar to it.But it's another language not English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling member function of number literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555853/calling-member-function-of-number-literal)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://shamansir.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/en/#object

> A common misconception is that number literals cannot be used as objects. That is because a flaw in JavaScript's parser tries to parse the dot notation on a number as a floating point literal.
>
> ```
> 2.toString(); // raises SyntaxError
> ```
>
> There are a couple of workarounds that can be used to make number literals act as objects too.
>
> ```
> 2..toString(); // the second point is correctly recognized
> 2 .toString(); // note the space left to the dot
> (2).toString(); // 2 is evaluated first
> ```

Comment: @Nikolay Tlnv: Thanks.When the JavaScript's parser meets 2.toString(),it doesn't know how parse the dot as 2.|toString() or 2|.toString().If there is another dot or space left to the dot the parser can treat it as a certain way.Is it right?