# Javascript auto inference using .toString()

Tags: javascript, object, interpreter, tokenize

Why doing this

```
123.toString()
```

gives an error...

but this

```
(123).toString()
```

Works OK

if possible and "at low level" answer (JIT/Interpreter parsing tokens decisions)

Comment: This is frequently asked, please wait while we search for you... EDIT : hard to search, this one, I find some but not any good ones...

Comment: Here's a better one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555853/calling-member-function-of-number-literal

Comment: hi dystroy... can you elaborate a little about .toFixed() ... ?objective ?version... thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript interpreter considers the `.` to be a decimal point, and therefore does not expect an alphabet character to follow it, hence the "unexpected token" error. Putting `123` in parentheses tells the interpreter, "run `toString()` on this object."

Comment: Why answer instead of voting to close as duplicate ?

Comment: or you can add a second point: 123..toString()

Comment: Thanks Igor... your answer was what has the knowledge I expected... I can´t believe I overlook the fact that the code parser was expecting a decimal point... You're the Man dude!!! ;-)

Comment: As we can see in this example the "mark/close/not contributive" marking agents start to be a bit Zelots... there should be a way for the person who put the question to fight this... although I believe that the majority or them are well intented... but this can diret use to miss such a good bit of knowledge as this one that Igor brought to us... ;-)

Comment: @ZEE We zelots try to avoid having tons of identical questions. When I mark a question as duplicate with a link to a QA having good answers, I don't expect an experienced user to prevent closing...

Comment: @ZEE what in the linked answers is included here but not in them? this is duplicated information and a duplicate question. If there are new answers that are not just re-hashing the same information they can be merged into the other question. As it stands, this is covered.

Comment: Whhooaaa PPL... I understand your point of view... the Zelots thing was just a teaser... I thanked Dystroy for his pointing to other answer... but I can't look away for the fact that the small answer gave here by other user gets fast to the point! we are all trying to get a better Comunity/knowlegebase here at Stackoverflow... And I'm just saying we should rethink some strategies :-)