# Cannot call toString() on numeric constant in Javascript

Tags: javascript

toString() doesn't work on numeric literal like `5.toString()`, but it works on string literal (`"str".toString()`) or after the numeric literal is assigned to `var`, like `var a = 5;a.toString()`. Wondering why it doesn't work for the first case?

Comment: Because there’d be a syntax ambiguity – the dot is used to denote decimals already, when it follows digits that make up a valid number..

Comment: @CBroe this makes sense. But it would not be hard to disambiguate the meaning of dot with just a little context.

Comment: [Calling member function of number literal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18555853/1529630) has a great answer which explains step by step why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first dot is the [decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark). You need a second one to access the property:

```
5..toString();
```

Comment: Didn't know about this. Learned something new but I find it a bit syntactically hard on the eyes over the parenthesis.

Comment: And kinda for completeness sake ;) – `032.toString()` works, because octal numbers can’t have decimals in JS.

Comment: @CBroe DecimalIntegerLiteral can't begin with `0`. Parsing it as  LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral is an optional extension not allowed in strict mode. But ES6 introduces proper OctalIntegerLiteral, and your approach works: `0o32.toString()`

Answer (score 7):

You can do this if you wrap it in parenthesis.

```
(5).toString();
```