# Why can't a variable be set to a <number>.toString(), but you can can call toString() on a return value?

Tags: javascript

```
function s(e) {
    return e.toString();
}

var a = s(3); // works

var b = 3.toString(); // error
```

For example, set var a to the return value of s() that returns the first argument.toString(), but you can't set var b to 3.toString()

Comment: Duplicate of [Why can't I access a property of an integer with a single dot?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9380077/218196)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is expecting number(s) after the decimal, you can still do this, but you need to put your number in parenthesis:

```
(3).toString() = "3"
```

Comment: Or `3..toString()` (not that this isn't even more confusing :P )