# Why toString() can be called on arguments but not directly

Tags: node.js

So I have this:

```
5.toString()
```

I get this error:

> ```
> console.log(5.toString());
>             ^^
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>     at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
>     at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
>     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
> ```

However, if I pass 5 using an intermediary function, it seems to cause no problems:

```
const foo = function(v){
  console.log(v.toString());
};


foo(5);   // no problem now
```

does anyone know why that runs without an error? I would think it would cause an exception. Maybe it's just a "compile-time" exception, not a runtime exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I access a property of an integer with a single dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380077/why-cant-i-access-a-property-of-an-integer-with-a-single-dot)

Comment: The `SyntaxError` tells you that it's a compile-time error, not a runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in parens like this:

```
(5).toString()
```

You can't use it the other way because the lexer is thinking you're typing out a decimal number

Comment: Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: Sounds like auto-boxing (what happens in Java too)...using parens makes it an object instead of a primitive.

Comment: I think `5..toString()` (with two dots) also does the same thing