# Why does 0.-5 evaluate to -5?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Suppose I write `0.5` as `0.-5` in unexpected way, but it can still run. What does `0.` in `0.-5` do so that it can still run and evaluates to -5?

I also tried `alert(0.-5+1)` which prints -4, does JavaScript ignore `0.` in `0.-5`?

Comment: `0.` is like `0.0`. Or just `0`.

Comment: What makes you think that `0.-5` is an "unexpected way"?

Comment: @NicoHaase: I'm pretty sure the OP used "unexpected way" to mean "I did not intend/expect to write that, but somehow I did".

Comment: This works in many other languages too (e.g. Python). I personally don't like it at all. I'd rather have `0.-5` be a syntax error and not allow float literals with a trailing period but force people to write `.0` at the end.

Comment: It's especially bad because allowing numbers to end in `.` prevents you from writing something like `123.toString(16)` (A common trick is to use `123..toString(16)`, which is really `(123.).toString(16)`)

Comment: @12Me21: Honestly, I don't think it's a good idea to write `123.toString(16)` anyway. `(123).toString(16)` is much clearer IMHO.

Comment: @12Me21 try `123 .toString()`.

Comment: Because that's what it means? Your preference?

Comment: `0.-5 = ((0.)-5) = ((0.)-(5)) = ((0)-(5)) = (0-5) = -5`

Comment: Did you expect that `-5` to be treated as *minus five tenths*, in other words `-5/10`?

Comment: @JohnDvorak `0.chr` being a method **call** bothers me way more than `0.` being a valid floating point literal.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta why? You can add parentheses to the call if you like, or you can think of it as property access even though it's actually a getter.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I don't like context-sensitive syntax if available. In `f(0.chr)` this is clearly passing the reference to method `chr` of object `0` to function `f` (and if this is not the case that's an other reason I wouldn't like Ruby). So `0.chr` being a method call in other contexts doe not make sense.

Comment: It's times like this that I realize Javascript's greatest strengths are also its greatest weaknesses. In this case it's a lack of linguistic structure that is the double edged sword.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Trailing digits after a `.` are optional:

```js
console.log(0. === 0); // true
```

So

```
0.-5
```

evalutes to

```
0 - 5
```

which is just `-5`. Similarly,

```
0.-5+1
```

is

```
0 - 5 + 1
```

which is

```
-5 + 1
```

or `-4`.

Comment: Leading digits are also optional, so .0-5 is also valid

Answer (score 49):

`0.-5` could be successfully parsed as `0.`<sup>[1]</sup>, `-` and `5`. Below is the abstract syntax tree for the expression generated by AST explorer:

[image: Parse tree generated by AST explorer]

This (in an unexpected way) is valid JavaScript and evaluates to `-5`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> According to [the grammar for numeric literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals) the decimal digits and exponent parts are optional:

> NumericLiteral ::
>     DecimalLiteral
>     [...]
>
> DecimalLiteral ::
>     DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigits<sub>opt</sub> ExponentPart<sub>opt</sub>

Comment: how did you extract the AST?

Comment: Go to https://astexplorer.net/, choose a language and a parser, paste the code, choose JSON output (or just take a screenshot).

Answer (score 40):

In JS you can express a number with optional decimal point.

```
x = 5.;    //5
x = 5. + 6.   //11
```

And as of Tvde1's comment, any Number method can be applied too.

```
5..toString()
```

This syntax let us run the Number functions without parentheses.

```
5.toString() //error
(5).toString() //good
5..toString() //good
5 .toString() // awesome
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380077/why-cant-i-access-a-property-of-an-integer-with-a-single-dot) question to find out why.

Comment: You can even do `5..toString()`.

Comment: If fact, you have to do 5..toString() to call the method, otherwise, you have to use parenthesis: (5).toString()

Comment: Not only in JavaScript. Is there even a language where this is not the case?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Ruby, for one. Also ALGOL 68. In Common Lisp, weirdly enough, `1.0` is floating point but `1.` is an integer.

Comment: Why would you write `5..toString()` if you can write `'5'` ?

Comment: So 5. parsing to 5 is tolerable but weird but why would two adjacent numbers parse? 0.-5 would parse to "0 -5" which seems like a syntax error.  I'm not completely familiar with JavaScript so it might be totally valid, I just don't know what it would mean.

Comment: @BillK In JavaScript, that would be parsed not as `(0) (-5)` but as `(0) - (5)`. The `-` is not parsed as being part of the integer, but rather as a unary operator.

Comment: @FlorianF You wouldn't, but that doesn't mean the parser should be special-cased to reject it. `float`s have methods, and `5.` is a `float`.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien The `-` would be parsed as a binary operator, not a unary one (if it were unary we'd have the same issue of two integers squished next to each other with no indication of what to do with them)

Comment: @PeterMortensen  Swift. Ending a numeric literal with a period is a compiler error. (`expected member name following '.'` for a lone `.`, or `use of unresolved operator '.-'` for `0.-5`)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Plenty. In any OO language where integers can be treated as objects with methods (except JavaScript because in this, as in so many other aspects, JavaScript is horrendously broken and poorly designed) the parse for a float requires digits after the dot specifically so you don't end up with the ambiguity that jo_va pointed out.

Comment: @Delioth my mistake, I meant binary. Thanks!

Comment: You could add `5 .toString() // awesome` to the list :)

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's certainly *not* the case that any other language where `(1).toMethod()` is legal prohibits `(1.)` from parsing properly. The most traditional approach to parsing (greedy lexing of tokens, including literals, then parsing) produces the Javascript behavior.

Answer (score 7):

I would think that the real answer is not about the decimal point, but is about the minus sign: isn't that going to be interpreted as an operator if it is preceded by anything that looks like a number?

Comment: Then, at least in some point of view, it still *is* about the decimal point being interpreted as part of a number literal, otherwise what preceded the minus sign wouldn't "looks like a number".

Answer (score 5):

```js
console.log(0. - 5)      // -5
console.log(0 - 5)       // -5
console.log('0.' - 5)    // -5
console.log('0' - 5)     // -5
console.log(0.-5 === -5) // true
```

'0.' or '0' is the same in JavaScript because the type is unique for numbers, called Number. The minus operator is between Numbers, try always to convert what you pass to a Number.
In Python is different first is a Float and the second an Integer because it has several types.

Comment: This issue is unrelated to types; it’s only related to syntax.