# Why is the output 0 here. var a = 7; a.constructor();

Tags: javascript, numbers

Let's look at the examples below:

**Q1:** Why is the output `0` here? What does it mean?

```js
var a = 7;
console.log(a.constructor()); // prints 0 (Why?)
```

**Q2:** When `typeof a` and `typeof 7` both are number, why `a.constructor()` runs whereas `7.constructor()` doesn't?

```js
var a = 7; 
var bool = typeof a === typeof 7;

console.log(a.constructor()); // 0
console.log((++a).constructor()); // 0

console.log(7.constructor()); // SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
console.log(++a.constructor()); // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation
```

Comment: `7.whatever` is simply incorrect syntax because the parser expects a numeric literal, .e.g. `7.123`. But you can go around it with `(7).whatever`

Comment: @VLAZ So, what is the difference between `(7).constructor()` and `7..constructor()`? Are they same?

Comment: @AadityaSharma the same. They'd avoid the dot being parsed as part of the numeric literal and just get `constructor`  from the Number representation of the primitive and execute it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I access a property of an integer with a single dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380077/why-cant-i-access-a-property-of-an-integer-with-a-single-dot)

Comment: @adiga good dupe. Unfortunately can't currently vote for it. Annoyingly, it only answers *half* the question because this question is...two questions. It's probably also Too Broad as the questions aren't really too much related.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post

Comment: @adiga: The thread is useful to this discussion. However, it answers only the 2nd half of the question.

Comment: There shouldn't be a "*2nd half of the question*" [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: Why is the output 0 here? What does it mean?

`a.constructor` is `Number` and you are calling it with first argument `undefined`. Because `Number()` returns `undefined` so `x.constructor()` returns `undefined`. If no argument is passed to `Number()` it returns `0`

```js
var a = 5;
console.log(a.constructor === Number)
console.log(Number())
```

> When typeof a and typeof 7 both are number, why a.constructor() runs whereas 7.constructor() doesn't?

Actually `7.` is itself a number. Here `.` doesnot work as Dot Notation but as decimal point because the digits after decimal point are optional.

#### Solution:

There can be different ways to directly access the method of number.

```js
console.log(5..constructor)
console.log((5).constructor)
console.log(5 .constructor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Because js number is object and has method `constructor` (which returns 0 when no parameter is provided)

Q2: Because first dot is interpret by js as decimal dot, but try

```js
console.log( 7..constructor() );
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do it this way but...it's so ugly. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

### Q1: Why is the output 0 here? What does it mean?

The constructor method is there to determine the type of the variable (Check the example)

```js
var a = 7;
console.log(a.constructor == Number);

var b = new Object;
console.log(b.constructor == Number);
console.log(b.constructor == Object);
```

### Q2: When typeof a and typeof 7 both are number, why a.constructor() runs whereas 7.constructor() doesn't?

Because the point after 7 is treated like a decimal and therefore it gives an error because `constructor()` is not a number. The code below would fix this (even tho it makes no sense):

```js
console.log((7).constructor())
```