# How is this function created? A = (0)['constructor']['constructor']

Tags: javascript, syntax

For an online challenge, I've deobfuscated some code to this:

```
A = (0)['constructor']['constructor']
```

From what I've tried, this function takes some code as parameter and puts it in the body of an anonymous function and returns it.

```js
A = (0)['constructor']['constructor']

console.log(A)
console.log(A('return 9'))
console.log(A('return 9')())
```

However, I don't understand this syntax and how the function is created. What's happening behind the scene ?

Comment: It's the same as `A = Function;`

Comment: Everything is an object in js, `(0).__proto__`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function

Comment: `0.constructor` is `Number`, `Number.constructor` is `Function`.

Comment: @Federkun: Primitive values are not, but some primitive data types have an Object equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a surprising amount going on here, so I'll try to break it down into steps.

- `0` is a primitive number. Primitives have no properties, and any attempt to retrieve a property (such as `(0).constructor`) will cause Javascript to automatically convert it to an Object representation. E.g. `(0)` becomes `Number(0)`.
- `(0)` is still a primitive, just with the addition of the grouping operators `()`. This is done here because, without the parentheses, the `.` in `0.` is interpreted as a decimal point rather than a property accessor. You could achieve the same thing with `0..constructor` or a number of other ways.
- All Javascript objects have a `prototype`. You can see an object's prototype using its `__proto__` property, e.g. `(0).__proto__`. The `prototype` is interesting because, when you try to access a property on the object, Javascript will also check the `__proto__` object to see if that property exists on it. (This is used mainly for inheritance).
- One of the properties on `__proto__` is `constructor`. The `constructor` is a function that is called when the object is first created.
- `constructor` is of type `Function`, which is itself an object with its own `constructor` property.

So, `(0).constructor.constructor` is shorthand for `Number(0).__proto__.constructor.__proto__.constructor`.

Your anonymous functions that return `9` do what they do because the constructor of a `Function` accepts as an argument a string representation of some Javascript code. It's equivalent to doing this:

`Function('return 9')()`;

Edit: corrected a mistake regarding autoboxing and `(0)`

Comment: "*This is useful because the syntax causes it to automatically convert the primitive 0 to an object*" - no, it does not. All the grouping parenthesis do is to *syntactically* allow the property access. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9380077/1048572) for details.

Comment: The "auto-boxing" happens when the property is accessed. A plain `const x = (0);` keeps a primitive number.

Comment: `0..toString` is valid syntax and accesses that property. The `()` have nothing to do with the internal conversion to an object.