# Why does 10..toString() work, but 10.toString() does not?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Why does calling `152..toString(2)` return a binary string value of `"10011000"`, when a call to `152.toString(2)` throws the following exception?

***`"SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal"`***

---

It seems to me that it's intuitive to want to use the latter call to `toString()`, as it looks & feels correct. The first example just seems plain odd to me.

***Does anyone know why JavaScript was designed to behave like this?***

Comment: Probably the parser tries to interpret 10.[andsomething] as a float number... just saying

Comment: Because when you want to cast a literal number to a string you just just use a literal string ("10"). AKA, who cares.

Comment: @SJuan76 Indeed.  Enclosing the 10 in parens will work `(10).toString()`

Comment: This is only a guess, but the parser probably thinks `toString` in `10.toString` is the start of a fraction, while in the later case you have 0 as fraction and then run toString on the float. This would probably mean that `var n = 10.;` would be valid as well (never tried though).

Comment: `10.0.toString()` is also works

Comment: This is another reason to hate java-derived languages.

Comment: 10. toString() - (with a space after the dot) works

Comment: The easiest way to call to string on a number is `(10).toString` no parser ambiguity there (I guess Matthew's suggestion works too, but it's tricky on the eye)

Comment: In case you were wondering, the equivalent `10.to_s` _is_ valid Ruby.  :)

Comment: So where's the case that you want to call toString on a literal number?

Comment: Why would you ever call `toString()` on a numberic literal when you can just include a string literal instead?

Comment: @nnnnnn: to convert it. In reality I'm calling it differently. I will edit the question

Comment: I wonder where all the hits to this question are coming from?  It's had stacks more attention today than it did the day it was asked.

Comment: seems to be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853865/usage-of-tostring-in-javascript

Comment: @Sidath see the text at the top of the question...

Answer (score 104, accepted):

A `.` after a number might seem ambiguous. Is it a decimal or an object member operator?

However, the interpreter *decides* that it's a decimal, so you're missing the member operator.

It sees it as this:

```
(10.)toString();  // invalid syntax
```

When you include the second `.`, you have a decimal followed by the member operator.

```
(10.).toString();
```

---

*@pedants and downvoters*

The `.` *character* presents an *ambiguity*. It can be understood to be the member operator, or a decimal, depending on its placement. If there was no ambiguity, there would be no question to ask.

The specification's interpretation of the `.` character in that particular position is that it will be a decimal. This is defined by the numeric literal syntax of ECMAScript.

Just because the specification resolves the ambiguity for the JS interpreter, doesn't mean that the ambiguity of the `.` character doesn't exist at all.

Comment: why the interpreter decides so ? Is there any spec about that? I makes still no sense to me, the interpreter should treat it like a property because its much more likely....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6853910/1026459

Comment: The `.` is *not* ambiguous.  See my answer.

Comment: @Alnitak: It presents an ambiguity because what would otherwise appear to be a valid placement of the same character could have two different behaviors. I'm not saying the specification is ambiguous. I'm saying the syntax is. The ambiguity is resolved in a specified manner.

Comment: Lexers don't deal in ambiguity.  *Parsers* do that.  By the time these two expressions get to the parser the lexer has already made an unambiguous decision about which characters are grouped into which token.

Comment: @Alnitak: How does the lexer decide what is a valid numeric literal?

Comment: by scanning characters until it finds a sequence which is no longer valid.  A JS numberic literal cannot have more than one decimal point in it, so as soon as the second one is seen it emits a token with everything seen _up to_ (but not including) that point.

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, but how does it decide what is and is not valid? It decides according to the numeric literal syntax specified in ECMAScript. So there's an ambiguity because the same token is used for two different purposes, but the ambiguity is resolved by the spec.

Comment: the dot is a _character_, not a _token_.

Comment: @pst: I think you're trying to push my use of the word into a corner. From the perspective of the developer, it's ambiguous. If it wasn't, the developer wouldn't be having this issue.

Comment: I would say "it is parsed as a decimal", but that is a larger change to the wording then I was willing to commit to.

Comment: @user1689607 re: your edit - every character is legal within a string literal.  Does that make _them_ ambiguous too?

Comment: @Alnitak: Discussions have context, but in a broader sense yes. The behavior of the characters within a string literal could be interpreted to have different meanings.

Comment: @Alnitak:  Your answer states *"The lexer ... when it sees a digit will keep consuming characters ... until it sees a character that is not part of a legal number."* Are you saying that once a lexer sees a digit, it will only consume characters that are part of a legal number, and it will then halt? Are you saying that its behavior is identical when it finds a digit within a string or regex literal? I felt no need to call you out on this, because it would be mere pedantry to do so.

Comment: @user1689607 yes, I omitted a step - the text I wrote applies when the lexer is reading a _new_ token.

Answer (score 101):

The lexer (aka "tokenizer") when reading a new token, and upon first finding a digit, will keep consuming characters (i.e. digits or **one** dot) until it sees a character that is *not* part of a legal number.

`<152.>` is a legal token (the trailing 0 isn't required) but `<152..>` isn't, so your first example reduces to this series of tokens:

```
<152.> <.> <toString> <(> <2> <)>
```

which is the legal (and expected) sequence, whereas the second looks like

```
<152.> <toString> <(> <2> <)>
```

which is illegal - there's no period token separating the Number from the `toString` call.

Comment: This is the clearest and most accurate answer, it should be accepted over the user1689607 one.

Comment: As a sidenote jsparse (http://jsparse.meteor.com/) has a realtime js lexer/parser, where you can see that the js engine parses "10." as a number.

Comment: @SzabolcsKurdi: That thing is *gorgeous*!

Answer (score 0):

`10.` is a `float number` an you can use toString on `float`

eg.

```
parseFloat("10").toString() // "10"
```

Comment: Well 1 is a int and you can call int on a float too, the real problem is parser ambiguity, as user1689607 mentioned

Comment: @JuanMendes: there is no such thing as `int` in javascript

Comment: @thg435 There's not a type called `int`, but internally ints and floats are represented differently. My point is that the parser reads is as an integer, and `10.toString()` is ambiguous, it's impossible to tell if the . is for property access or the start of a float

Comment: @JuanMendes the lexer and parser don't treat ints and floats separately.  There's simply no such thing as an "integer literal" in JS.

Comment: @JuanMendes (unless it's in hex, that is)

Comment: Why not just use `(10).toString()` ?