# Why 42.toString() fails in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

### Disclaimer

Guys, I **DO** aware of [Why does 10..toString() work, but 10.toString() does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149282/why-does-10-tostring-work-but-10-tostring-does-) question existence, but the thing is that it doesn't provide the formal explanation.

> The specification's interpretation of the . character in that particular position is that it will be a decimal. This is defined by the numeric literal syntax of ECMAScript.

Without reference to a standard isn't trustable enough

### The question body

I subconsciously understand that

```
42..toString()
```

is treated by a parser as a `42.` number followed by a `.toString()` call.

What I cannot understand is why an interpreter cannot realize that

```
42.toString()
```

is a `42` followed by a method call.

Is it just a drawback of modern JS interpreters or is it explicitly stated by ES5.1?

From ES5.1 the [Numeric Literal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) is defined as (only significant part of definition):

```
NumericLiteral ::
    DecimalLiteral
    HexIntegerLiteral

DecimalLiteral ::
    DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigits(opt) ExponentPart(opt)
    . DecimalDigits ExponentPart(opt)
    DecimalIntegerLiteral ExponentPart(opt)
```

The last rule is what I expect to be chosen by a parser.

**UPD**: to clarify, this question expects as an answer references to ES specification that state explicitly that interpreter must behave like it does

Comment: Is this the example I used in my previous comment

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫: that's exactly it :-)

Comment: The `.` in `DecimalLiteral` doesn't seem to be optional.

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫: see the line #3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the piece you're missing is [this quote from section 7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7):

> The source text is scanned from left to right, repeatedly taking the longest possible sequence of characters as the next input element.

Note "longest possible sequence of characters"; since "42." is a valid token (which is a kind of input element), it must be used rather than "42" and then ".".

Comment: Valid syntax: `42..toString()`, `(42).toString()`, and `42 .toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

The lexical phase of the parsing process consumes the `.` precisely due to the definition of `NumericLiteral` quoted from the standard. The definition specifies that a numeric literal (here a `DecimalLiteral`) includes a `.`, if present - see the first line under `DecimalLiteral ::`.

Since `42.` is consumed by the numeric literal token, the next token is `toString`, which lacks a leading period and therefore cannot be recognized as method call.

Comment: "precisely due to the definition of NumericLiteral quoted from the standard" --- see the `DecimalIntegerLiteral ExponentPart(opt)` rule which doesn't have a required `.`

Comment: @zerkms It is not required, but it's there in your example, and the lexer will consume it for the token.

Comment: that is the whole point of my question - why it does that. And another answer explains that. Whereas this one is based on... on what actually?

Comment: @zerkms Even without the sentence quoted in Jesse Rusak's answer, EcmaScript would still behave the same. Context-free grammars do not go back to lexical analysis to try a different tokenization of input in case of syntax error.

Comment: "Context-free grammars do not go back to lexical analysis" --- what this statement is based on? Is it defined in ES? If yes - where? (this is the whole point of my question) If not, how am I supposed to know ES standard is based on a given kind of grammar?

Comment: @zerkms 5.1.1 and 5.1.2 make it clear that ES is specified with a context-free grammar. Also, section 7 explicitly states, *The source text of an ECMAScript program is first converted into a sequence of input elements, which are tokens, line terminators, comments, or white space.* I.e. tokenization is done first does not depend on grammatical interpretation of the input.

Comment: That should have been put into an answer, because that what was the question about (it's the 3rd time I'm mentioning about this in this conversation)

Comment: @zerkms You've made that point quite clear, yes. However, the question already quotes the standard, and the answer clearly refers to that quotation.

Comment: I promise it's the last comment here :-D From both the question and this answer it's not obvious why parser must prefer the last `DecimalLiteral` rule over the first.

Comment: @zerkms Actually, it must prefers the first. :) It may not be *obvious*, but it does follow from the widely understood meaning of the notation used in your quote. Consider this: if the lexer had the freedom to interpret the input `42.toString` as `42` followed by `.` followed by `toString`, the input `42.3` would become a syntax error. If the standard allowed the lexer to look ahead or be revisited after the syntactic analysis was shown to fail, then it wouldn't use a BNF-like notation nor mention context-free grammars in the first place.