# Is there difference between 1 and 1.0 in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss

I found a snippest about customized metrics.

```
smooth = 0.001
dices = (2. * a + smooth) / (a+ b+ smooth)

ratio = a/ (K.sum(a) + smooth)
ratio = 1.0 - ratio
```

Why the author prefer float number (like `2.` and `1.0`) instead of integers (`2` or `1`)?
And I found that a lot of people prefer using floating number instead of integers, I do not know why.

I guess if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149282/why-does-10-tostring-work-but-10-tostring-does-not) is the reason?

Comment: I think they will be automatically converted, but there are languages that may raise problems if you don't put the right type. I also think Python 2 works a little different from Python 3 there. So for safety, it's probably better to keep it float.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will show the difference between two.

```
t1 = tf.constant(value=1)
t1.dtype
```

Output
tf.int32

```
t2 = tf.constant(value=1.0)
t2.dtype
```

Output
tf.float32

**now adding these two tensors will throw an error as data type for these two are different.**

```
t3 = tf.add(x=t1, y=t2)
```

Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 527, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1224, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1018, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("Const_4:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)'

Comment: Thanks. I know in python, `t1=1;t2=1.0;t3=t1+t2` is OK, because python will automatically convert integers to floats. But I did not know that tensorflow can not do that.