# Syntax error, or no syntax error?

Tags: javascript

```
var zero = 0;
zero.toString();   // '0' --> fine
0.toString();      // syntax error!
0..toString();     // '0' --> fine
```

My conclusion: calling `x.toString()` doesn't only depend on the value of `x`, but also on the way `x` is *presented*.

Are there other such examples in JavaScript where I might get an unexpected syntax error due to presentation?

Comment: Another way is `(0).toString();`

Comment: from what i know the `.` operator for objects, 0 just like that isn't an object yet, as @epascarello showed, (0) will transform it into an object, making the `.` operator available... the `..` does the same effect but you could also use a more explicit way like Number(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are other cases where the *context* of where symbols appear affects how they behave, for example, statement Block's vs Object Literals:

```
{}          // empty block
var o = {}; // empty object
({});       // empty object
0,{}        // empty object

{ foo: 'bar'} // block, `foo` label, 'bar' ExpressionStatement
var o = { foo: 'bar'}; // object literal, declaring a `foo` property
                       // whose value is 'bar'
```

They look exactly the same, but blocks are evaluates in "statement context", object literals are evaluated in *expression context*.

Also, Function Declarations vs. Function Statements, e.g.:

```
function foo() {}.length;   // SyntaxError, `foo` is a function declaration
0,function foo() {}.length; // 0, `foo` is a function expression
(function foo {}).length;   // 0
```

The example you post, relates to the way the grammar of Numeric literals are defined, the decimal part after the dot is actually optional, for example:

```
var n = 0.;
```

Is a valid Numeric literal, that's why, accessing `0.toString` gives you a `SyntaxError`, the interpreter would expect the decimal part, instead the `s` character.

See also:

- [What does `1..something` mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300197/what-does-1-something-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The value of a variable doesn't matter, but the way it is "presented" might make it valid or invalid syntax. See this [highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/3297392#3297392). It's just an oddity of the EcmaScript syntax definition.