# Why does accessing a property directly on an Object literal throw a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript

When trying to access the property `a` of the object `{}`

```
{}.a
```

I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

With parens all is fine:

```
({}).a
```

Why do I get an error in the fist place? Is there ambiguity?

Comment: JavaScript syntax just doesn't allow that.

Comment: The expression `{}` evaluates to a new native object which has no own properties. Are you trying to access one of the `Object.prototype` methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Immediately accessing an object's property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518538/immediately-accessing-an-objects-property)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The curly braces are interpreted as a [block statement](http://es5.github.com/x12.html#x12.1), not as an object literal. You cannot begin an expression statement with a left curly brace.

The specification states:

> **NOTE** An *ExpressionStatement* cannot start with an opening curly brace
>   because that might make it ambiguous with a *Block*. Also, an
>   *ExpressionStatement* cannot start with the `function` keyword because
>   that might make it ambiguous with a *FunctionDeclaration*.

Source: http://es5.github.com/x12.html#x12.4

Answer (score 1):

the {} are there to build the object. usually you first assign the new object to a variable.

```
var o = {
    a: "b"
};

console.log(o.a);
```

but this is also possible:

```
console.log({
    a: "b"
}.a);
```