# What are the rules for invoking functions on number literals in JS?

Tags: javascript

Since I started working with JS, I've thought the only way to invoke a function on a number literal is to put it in expression position by wrapping it with parens, like so:

```js
1.toString();
// SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

(1).toString();
// "1"
```

Today, it occurred to me to try this:

```js
0.1.toString();
// "0.1"
```

Why does this work?  A pointer into the official spec would be great.

**Edit** Ambiguity was my first thought, but then decided that there's no ambiguity in `1.toString()` either.  It's deeper than I first thought, but I still think I'm right.  Here's why:

**Property names *can* begin with digits**

```js
var obj = { "1" : 1, "2" : 2 };
```

**Property names that begin with digits can only be referenced with square brackets**

```js
obj.1;
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
obj['1'];
// 1
```

Also:

```js
1['toString']();
// '1'
```

Therefore, `1.` followed by any non-digit will always be a method call or property access, never a decimal number.  Likewise, `1.` followed by any digit will always be a decimal number, never a method call or property access.

Comment: as a note, you could use `1..toString()`, the first `.` indicates the decimal point, the second indicates usage for the function.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2300197

Comment: Clever, thanks zzzzBov and CMS.

Comment: Well there's a *small* ambiguity around "e" - is it the start of an exponent, or is it the first letter of an identifier? Consider `1.e10();` - tokenizers don't like having to "back up" :-)

Comment: I don't follow... that would be written `1e10`, no?

Comment: I don't agree with marking this duplicate.  The question contains more context and the chosen answer is higher quality (including a link to the actual JavaScript spec where this behavior is defined).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once it's seen the first `.` in `0.1`, then a subsequent `.` *cannot* be part of the number.

It's all about ambiguity.

*edit* — section 7.8.3 of the spec explicitly insists on this:

> The source character immediately following a NumericLiteral must not be an *IdentifierStart* or *DecimalDigit*.

I'm not sure exactly what that's trying to prevent, but the JavaScript lexer is pretty gnarly, mostly thanks to the regex literal grammar and the need for a weird parser-lexer hack to deal with that.

Comment: I don't think there's any ambiguity here.  Updating my question with the reasoning.  I'm confused by that sentence from the spec... `0.1.toString()` is valid, but looks to me like a NumericLiteral immediately followed by a DecimalDigit.

Comment: @mwcz Yes, I agree that there's no *apparent* ambiguity, but there might be some obscure reason for the insistence that the case be treated as an error. The spec doesn't go into any real detail. And `0.1.toString` is *not* a numeric literal followed by a decimal digit: it's a numeric literal followed by a `.` character, which is neither a decimal digit nor an identifier start.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I looked at `.` and couldn't distinguish it from `.` :)  I've added the reasoning against ambiguity, although I'm guessing you've arrived at it independently.